# How to merge two nodes in AWS Glue pyspark script

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a bunch of JSON files that I need to process. The structure (simplified for example) of the JSON files are (Schema of catalog when aws glue crawler ran on those json files):

```
root
|-- Meta: struct
|    |-- DataModel: string
|    |-- EventType: string
|    |-- EventDateTime: string
|-- User: struct
|    |-- Demographics: struct
|    |    |-- FirstName: string
|    |    |-- MiddleName: string
|    |    |-- LastName: string
```

I wish to merge or join **User.Demographics.FirstName** with **User.Demographics.MiddleName** 
and **User.Demographics.LastName**.
So that the final processed JSON would look like:

```
root
|-- Meta: struct
|    |-- DataModel: string
|    |-- EventType: string
|    |-- EventDateTime: string
|-- User: struct
|    |-- Demographics: struct
|    |    |-- Name: string
```

I went through the [AWS glue Developers Guide describing DynamicFrams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-schema) and permitted options, but couldn't find any function that seems to be helpful.

As of now, I have following code that was auto-generated by AWS Glue, but doesn't seem to work.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = <db_name>, table_name = <table_name>, transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = <db_name>, table_name = <table_name>, transformation_ctx = "datasource0")


## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: <Currently using mapping function>
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [<Mapping Tuples>], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")


## @type: DataSink
## @args: [connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": <S3 Destination Path>}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2"]
## @return: datasink2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
# datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = applymapping1, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": <S3 Destination Path>}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink2")
job.commit()
```

AWS Glue also supports PySpark library of python, if there's a way to implement this using PySpark, please share some details/links where I can refer to it.

P.S. 
I have some experience in writing scripts in Python but don't have any idea about python's PySpark library or any other ETL related code/scripting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the map transformation. The function passed as parameter in the map operation accepts a dict, you can execute any logic and return an updated or new dict.

See the example in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you can refer to these link, or other link for merging columns in a dataframe. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643550/how-to-merge-two-columns-with-a-condition-in-pyspark](http://May%20be%20you%20can%20refer%20to%20these%20link,%20or%20other%20link%20for%20merging%20columns%20in%20a%20dataframe.%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643550/how-to-merge-two-columns-with-a-condition-in-pyspark).  You may need to tweak or modify the code to suit your needs